# Can I get a webpack resolve alias working on android with expo?

Tags: react-native, webpack, expo

I'm trying to get a preact library to work with expo/react-native

It works find on web using this alias in webpack:

```js
// webpack.config.js
const createExpoWebpackConfigAsync = require('@expo/webpack-config');
module.exports = async function(env, argv) {
  const config = await createExpoWebpackConfigAsync(env, argv);
  config.resolve.alias = {
    ...config.resolve.alias,
    'preact': 'react'
  }
  return config;
};
```

But on android I get an error: `Unable to resolve "preact" from "node_modules/.../...`.

Does anyone know how to get the same kind of alias working outside of web?

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to find a solution where webpack's alias was usable outside of Web on Android.  I needed it on account of the typical [invalid Hook call caused by duplicate React modules being used.](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html)

Supposedly Yarn workspaces might fix this as well but I couldn't get that working.

The solution I found and was mildly painless was to update my local libraries' `devDependencies` so they all use the same React module being used in the main project's `dependencies`.

```
- app
  |
  |-- package.json dependency:    "react":"18.1.0"
  
- local_library
  |
  |-- package.json devDependency:    
    "react": "file:../../../node_modules/react",
```